# Need Help Naming Class

Tags: java, naming

I have a class which analyzes a string and if the string is not null or an empty string, it creates a new String or new Date using the object depending on the type of subclass.  If the string is null or empty it returns an empty string.  Currently I call this class converter however I feel this name is misleading, is there a better name anyone can think of for what this class is doing?  I want something intuitive that will make my code more readable.  Thanks.

```
public abstract class Converter {
    Object returnObject;

    public Converter() {

    }

    public Object convert(String value)
    {
        if(!this.isEmpty(value))
        {
            this.setReturnObject(value);    
        }else
        {
            this.returnObject = "";
        }
        return this.getReturnObject();
    }

    protected boolean isEmpty(String value)
    {
        return (value != null && value.equalsIgnoreCase(""));
    }

    protected abstract void setReturnObject(String value);

    protected Object getReturnObject(){
        return this.returnObject;
    }
}

public class NumberConverter extends Converter {
    public NumberConverter() {
    }

    protected void setReturnObject(String value) {
        this.returnObject = new Number(Integer.parseInt(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it belongs here: http://english.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: I think I'm in the right forum.  Naming is a huge part of producing readable code at least according to the Uncle Bob books Clean Coder and Clean Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either EntityMapper  or EntityTransformer.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Entity' prefix is not appropriate because the class is not taking an entity, but a String.

I also would not choose transformer (or converter) because the original value does not change (being an immutable String kind of rules that out).

I would go for StringMapper or maybe StringParser (as suggested by Burleigh Bear).

On a side note, you could use generics to specify the mapped/parsed types and make this code a bit more typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

i guess abstract class doesnt contain any method definations inside it...!!
better check that thing first..!!

and as far as naming is concerned i would give agree with sathwick.
Thanks. :)

Comment: abstract class can contain method definitions in it. It is a valid case. Only interfaces can not have method definitions in it.

Comment: @indyaah, I'm not sure what you mean by abstract class doesn't contain any method definitions inside it? If you mean abstract methods that the implementers must override did you see: protected abstract void setReturnObject(String value);
?

Comment: yeah..
my mistake...
i guess i got confused in between abstract class and interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're taking a string and parsing it, I'd say "Parser".